# Get a cell value from two different cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been trying to find out how to get a cell value based on two other cells. The formula I'm using is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(C3)),
IF(C3="","",
IF((C3-NOW())>0, "Call restaurant in "&ROUND(C3-NOW(),2)&" days", 
"Call now")),))
```

Is it possible to add a formula that will detect if there is text in the cell in column V as indicated in green below? The message will be "do not call" else if the cell is empty the message will be "call restaurant in" or "call now" based on the left time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, just add another layer to your `IF` statement. Note sure why the second condition is there (if it's not blank, then if it is blank, return blank...), but will leave it in the suggestion below under the assumption that it is there for a reason.

In Excel:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(C3)),
IF(C3="","",
IF(V3<>"", "do not call", 
IF((C3-NOW())>0, "Call restaurant in "&ROUND(C3-NOW(),2)&" days", 
"Call now"))))
```